# Explain MySQL query without changing row_count() from previous query

Tags: mysql, database-performance, rowcount

In an application, sometimes queries are slow, and I "explain" them after the fact (if they are slow) and log them, so I can improve the application over time.

However, if I run an "explain " after, row_count() no longer reflects the number of rows affected by the original query, which I don't want. Is there a way to run an explain query (or perhaps any query), and not change row_count()?

Note: What I am currently doing is to open a separate link to the database, and explain using that link. That works, but I am unable to explain queries using temporary tables in that way. I am looking for a different solution that will preserve row_count() and work with temporary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture `row_count()` into a variable, if you need it later.  You should probably be doing this anyway, since the scope of validity of this value is very limited.

The value is tied to the specific connection, and is reset with each query you execute... and `EXPLAIN ...` is a query.

There's not a way to change this behavior.

Comment: Your answer was my original thought, but in various places in the application (not written by me) there is "select row_count()" hard coded; any change will break those. I've considered doing something nominal in the database to change row_count() back to the original value after the explain query, but that is at best a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code...

```
SELECT ...
get ROW_COUNT ...
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

Note also that `EXPLAIN's` "Row" column is an approximation; it will rarely match `ROW_COUNT()`.